# MySQL in Orange 3

Tags: mysql, orange

I read documentation for Orange 3. It says 'Widgets can read data from (Postgres) SQL and pass around queries. Viva AXLE!'. Are you going to still provide support for MySQl to write Sql queries in Orange 3?

Comment: Try a different place for this question, not related to anything here.

Comment: What makes you think that we have anything to do with Orange's development roadmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orange 3 is eventually going to support other databases as well, but the current focus is on PostgreSQL due to ongoing project that partially funds the development. Is there any particular reason you need to use MySQL?

The support for databases in Orange 3 goes beyond just loading the data from the database, so it cannot be completely generic.

(I see you got some downvotes by MySQL people for adding the mysql tag. Perhaps you should better try MariaDB tag next time. :)